# 特定のNuxt.jsプロジェクトでrun devした際に高確率でロードに失敗する

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

環境
`"nuxt": "2.8.1"`
`"node": "12.5.0"`
`"npm": "6.9.0"`

にて `npm run dev` を実行し、localでサーバを建てた後にアクセスしようとすると1/2くらいの確率でロードアイコンがくるくる回り続け、アクセスできない状態になります。

ログとしては以下の通りで、特に致命的な異常が見当たらず、ChromeのNertwork、Consoleタブでも何も情報が出ておらず、問題究明ができずに困っています。
1/2くらいの確率で普通に使え、初回アクセスができればそのあとは問題なく動くので、動くまで再起動を繰り返していますが、ビルドが1分半かかるので時間の無駄感が半端ではないです。

因みに
・他のプロジェクトを新規作成して実行
・サーバにアップロード
した際に同じ問題が発生することはありませんでした。
推測レベルでも良いので何か情報をいただけますと幸いです。

```
(base) user:projectDir$ npm run dev

> project@1.0.0 dev /Users/projectDir
> PORT=8080 nuxt

2020-06-13T02:35:24.943Z                                              11:35:24

   ╭─────────────────────────────────────────────╮
   │                                             │
   │   Nuxt.js v2.8.1                            │
   │   Running in development mode (universal)   │
   │   TypeScript support is enabled             │
   │                                             │
   │   Listening on: http://localhost:8080/      │
   │                                             │
   ╰─────────────────────────────────────────────╯

ℹ Preparing project for development                                   11:35:28
ℹ Initial build may take a while                                      11:35:28
✔ Builder initialized                                                 11:35:28
✔ Nuxt files generated                                                11:35:28

 WARN  Browserslist: caniuse-lite is outdated. Please run next command npm update

ℹ Starting type checking service...                                   11:35:32
ℹ Using 1 worker with 2048MB memory limit                             11:35:32

✔ Client
  Compiled successfully in 1.30m

✔ Server
  Compiled successfully in 1.16m

ℹ No type errors found                                                11:36:50
ℹ Version: typescript 3.5.3                                           11:36:50
ℹ Time: 13296ms                                                       11:36:50

ℹ Waiting for file changes                                            11:36:50
ℹ Memory usage: 790 MB (RSS: 1.16 GB)
```

Comment: localhost:8080のようなホストでアクセスされてますか？もし仮にそれを127.0.0.1:8080のようなアドレスでアクセスした場合も状況は同じですか？

Comment: ありがとうございます。アドレスでアクセスしてみましたが、同じですね。。。

Answer (score 1):

自己解決しました。nuxt2.4を使っていたのですがバージョン依存のバグだったようです。
最新版では解決されています。